# Prestashop TCPDF validation errors

Tags: php, validation, pdf, prestashop, tcpdf

I'm using tcpdf on generating pdf files out of html-snippets out of the prestashop (Version 1.6) source code.

Everything seems fine on viewing the pdf in Adobe Reader. On trying to send it via an electronic-fax service (e-post.de) i'm not abled to upload the file,...sadly without an error log or message.

On checking generated file on http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx, i'm getting this result:

```
Validating file "AYTKXFQRB_TestEins.pdf" for conformance level pdfa-3b
The required XMP property 'pdfaid:part' is missing.
The required XMP property 'pdfaid:conformance' is missing.
The embedded font program 'AAAAAB+ArialMT' cannot be read.
A device-specific color space (DeviceRGB) without an appropriate output intent is used.
The embedded font program 'AAAAAC+ArialMT,Bold' cannot be read.
The glyph for character 8364 in font 'AAAAAB+ArialMT' is missing.
The glyph for character 8364 in font 'AAAAAC+ArialMT,Bold' is missing.
The width for character 0 in font 'AAAAAB+ArialMT' does not match.
The width for character 0 in font 'AAAAAC+ArialMT,Bold' does not match.
The document does not conform to the requested standard.
The document contains device-specific color spaces.
The document contains fonts without embedded font programs or encoding information (CMAPs).
The document's meta data is either missing or inconsistent or corrupt.
Done.
```

I think, there are a lot of warnings which can be ignored. Files generated directly out of Adobe InDesign are also containing the majority of these warnings. The only warnings which seems to be hurting are these:

The required XMP property 'pdfaid:part' is missing.
The required XMP property 'pdfaid:conformance' is missing.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

EDIT:

Solution for the xmp-Error:

Setting the flag pdfa=true on calling the constructor to activate the pdfa_mode ...

```
public function __construct($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $format='A4', $unicode=true, $encoding='UTF-8', $diskcache=false, $pdfa=false)
```

But I have to still get rid of the font-errors :-(

Comment: Does e-post require PDF/A files?

Comment: Like mentioned in the FAQ of e-post ... yes